# Disable an image element after first click on toggle, then re-enable it using setTimeout in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout

I am building a parking slot feature so as to allocate parking slots to users using `reservation time`. What I am trying to achieve is, when a user `first clicks` on the image element, the image `toggles` to a second image then `disables` the toggle functionality for a certain time(reservation time), for which then the user can't click the image element for the second time until reservation time expires. The set timeout will later simulate `onClick` and `toggle` the image back to its initial state. So far I have used a `set timeout` in the toggleActive() but the toggle state doesn't toggle as expected depending on the `set timeout` functionality. Here is the code of what I have done so far:

```
// === toggleActive() === toggles the active image by id, selected by the user
  function toggleActive(index) {
    let arrayCopy = [...slotState.slots];

    const countDownDate = new Date("September 4, 2020 00:00:00").getTime();

    
      const now = new Date().getTime();

      // duration === (Reservation time) === to reserve a parking slot
      const reservationTime = countDownDate - now;


    // if arrayCopy[index].toggled equals to true then toggled is *false* else toggled is *true*
    arrayCopy[index].toggled
      ? setTimeout(()=>{
        return(arrayCopy[index].toggled = false)},reservationTime)
      : (arrayCopy[index].toggled = true);
    changeState({ ...slotState, slots: arrayCopy });
  }


function toggleActiveImage(index) {
    if (slotState.slots[index].toggled) {
      // === parkingImages.unavailable === is a red image(Indicating the slot is assigned)
      return parkingImages.unavailable;
    } else {
      // === parkingImages.unavailable === is a blue image(Indicating the slot is not assigned)

      return parkingImages.available;
    }
  }


const renderSlots = slotState.slots.map((slot, index) => {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-1" style={{ width: "auto" }} key={index}>
        <img
          key={index}
          src={toggleActiveImage(index)}
          style={{ width: "3rem", cursor: "pointer" }}
          alt="parking"
          onClick={() => toggleActive(index)}
        />
        <p style={{ fontSize: ".8rem", fontWeight: "500" }}>
          slot-{slot.slot_no}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  });
```

I really hope there's a solution to the above problem, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it,

```
const reservationTime = 3000;
const Slots = (props) => {
  const [slots, setSlots] = React.useState(props.slots);

  const disableSlot = (selectedIndex) => {
    // Check if slot is active at the time of clicking.
    if (slots[selectedIndex].active === true) {
      const updatedSlots = slots.map((slot, index) => {
        if (selectedIndex === index) {
          slot.active = false;
        }
        return slot;
      });
      setSlots(updatedSlots);
      setTimeout(() => {
        activateSlot(selectedIndex);
      }, reservationTime);
    }
  };

  const activateSlot = (selectedIndex) => {
    const updatedSlots = slots.map((slot, index) => {
      if (selectedIndex === index) {
        slot.active = true;
      }
      return slot;
    });
    setSlots(updatedSlots);
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      {slots.map((slot, index) => {
        return (
          <li key={slot.id} onClick={() => disableSlot(index)}>
            {slot.name} - Active: {String(slot.active)}
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};
```